# Why does this Java for loop terminate although it is supposed to loop infinitely?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, jvm, bytecode

The following loop is supposed to be looping endlessly, or so I think.

```
int y=0;
for(int x=1; x>0; x++)
{
    y=y+x;
}
```

However, the loop does terminate, and I do not know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually x will be greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE and then it will overflow to negative
Here is a quick test to show you what I mean

```
int val = 1000000;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     val = val * val;
     if (val < 0) {
         System.out.println(val);
     }
}
```